# Программа постоянно просит права админа, как включить постоянно?

Tags: windows, windows-8

я работаю в системе под обычным пользователь, есть admin 
Ну вот когда что то устанавливаю, всегда запрашиваются права админа и я соглашаюсь если считаю что все норм.

Дак вот, у меня установлены 2 приложения, которые меня смущают, это мторрент и скриншот.

Постоянно при запуске системы, скриншот спрашивает админ права..
А каждый раз при запуске мторрента, или клике по файлу, также спрашивает админ права, дело в том что я когда устанавливал мторрент, он чето не сохранял настройки, но помню что ставил его под админом. 
Ну и включил в свойствах - запускать программу от имени администратора.

Вот что делать, постоянно теперь так, хотя на ноуте все также устанавливал под админом - все работает там без повторных запросов.

в чем дело?
Как сказать чтоб он запускал программу либо постоянно от админа без вопросов либо как пофиксить это?

Comment: `Правой кнопкой по программе > Свойства > Совместимость > Изменить параметры для всех пользователей > Выполнять эту программу от имени администратора` - этим мы сделаем запуск программы по умолчанию от имени администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска без UAC-окна можно использовать планировщик Windows, но вообще я бы советовал разобраться с ситуацией. Скорее всего, нужно поправить права и владельцев конфигурационных файлов.

Comment: чето не получается, как прова менять я вижу, а какие права указать то? и каким файлам?

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг, тем, что сейчас недоступны для изменения без прав администратора.